# Proper way to use "props" in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm creating a new project using VueJS as first time, and trying to use a toolbar on all of my pages. But I want to make the title present in the toolbar, dynamic.
I tried to use props, but I must be wrong the way I use it. Check the example below :

In my index.html :

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
    <v-app>
        <spa-toolbar :title="title"></spa-toolbar>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </v-app>
</div>

<script>
    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    Vue.use(VeeValidate);
    Vue.config.devtools = true;

    const routes = [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: spaLogin,
            props: {title: 'Connexion'}
        },
        {
            path: '/parametres',
            name : 'parametres',
            component: spaParametres,
            props: {title: 'Paramètres'}
        },
    ];

    let router = new VueRouter({
        hashbang: false,
        routes
    });

    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
        next();
    });


    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        watch: {},
        data: {
            title: 'Connexion',
        },
        router
    });
</script>
```

toolbar.vue.js (with the "props: ["title"]) :

```
 <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">{{title}}</v-toolbar-title>
```

And in another page "parametres.vue.js" I'm using the props["title"], but the value of the title is always "Connexion", the value defined in my main App in index.html.

How can I make this value dynamic ? Thought passing it through the router would be great...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the property `title` from the `v-app` component to the `spa-toolbar` component. Then you are setting a property on the routes which is also called `title`.

These two are not related in any way. Also the `title` prop from the route is passed to the component in `router-view`, i.e. `spaLogin` and `spaParametre`.

So I think a better way would be to define a `meta` field on the route:

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
    <v-app>
        <spa-toolbar :title="(($route.matched[0] || {}).meta || {}).title"></spa-toolbar>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </v-app>
</div>

<script>
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
Vue.config.devtools = true;

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: spaLogin,
        meta: {title: 'Connexion'}
    },
    {
        path: '/parametres',
        name : 'parametres',
        component: spaParametres,
        meta: {title: 'Paramètres'}
    },
];

let router = new VueRouter({
    hashbang: false,
    routes
});

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {},
        router
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seems to work :/. Should my route for "parametres" still be like this ? : 

{
            path: '/parametres',
            name : 'parametres',
            component: spaParametres,
            props: {title: 'Paramètres'}
 },

Comment: Ah right, that is another problem. The prop from the route is given to the `spaParametres` component, not the `v-app` component... @WebFreak, let me suggest another solution.

Comment: Maybe my app is not built like it should be (:, I took my app example from : https://github.com/sobpilot/vuespa , but the title on their toolbar doesn't seems to work either :D

Comment: @WebFreak, please have a look now. Still might not work exactly, because `$route.matched` returns `/` and `/parametres` when you go to `/parametres`, but I think you can figure out the rest.